# Where is the old audience overview report on Google Analytics 4 ? (New Version)

Tags: google-analytics

Can anyone help me find the old audience overview report on Google Analytics 4, the Graph is wider and nice and shows page views and bounce rate, on the new audience report does not look the same? does it still exist?

[image: https://snipboard.io/cy5mQ2.jpg]

Comment: Ok, so let's vote for question migration, not closing.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics 4 the paradigm has changed, everything is considered an `event`, consequently many of the reports from Universal Analytics have been removed in GA4.

`Bounce Rate` has been replaced by a new metric called `Engagement Rate` in Google Analytics 4.